# mysql join query with php

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
table: database1.comment
id | owner_id | comment    
1  |  1       | some words 
2  |  1       | some words
3  |  2       | some words

table: database2.users
id | display_name
1  | admin    
2  | guest
```

I am try to join 2 tables query, here is my php code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database1.comment INNER JOIN database2.users ON database1.comment.owner_id=database2.users.id order by database1.comment.id DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     echo '<li>'.$row['display_name'].': '.$row['comment'].'</li>';
}
```

I get a error message: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`. How to make a work code ( optimize way )

Comment: Well, your query failed. Check for errors before attempting to fetch rows.  `if (!$result) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: You're getting an error. Try calling mysql_error() and post the error message.

Comment: The syntax looks ok, but it might be a database user permission issue across two dbs.

Comment: I think you need to use mysql_query like this: 'mysql_query("SELECT <everything same> DESC;");` //Notice the extra `;` inside

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog No, the PHP MySQL extension doesn't expect `;` statement terminators.

Comment: @Michael, um, right, 2 database with different username and password.

Comment: @fishman There ya go then. If you need to query 2 dbs with one connection, you'll need [to grant access](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) for the currently connected user...

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is invalid (or otherwise "failed"), mysql_query() returns "false" (instead of an array).

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Cut/paste your SQL string into MySQL, see what's incorrect, and fix it.  And that point, your PHP should be OK.
2. Check your result (and gracefully handle any failures/errors) in your code:

EXAMPLE (error: no "from" clause):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query return resource on success and boolen false on failure when there is no results.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php